# window.window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why window object in the browser points to window object. Mozilla Website states the reason as

> The point of having the window property refer to the object itself was (probably) to make it easy to refer to the global object (otherwise you'd have to do a manual `var window = this;` assignment at the top of your script).

So, my question is, how to infinitely point an object to object and how that helps to avoid doing `var window = this;`

```
window.window // returns window object
window.window.window // also returns an window
```

Comment: what do you mean by `how to infinitely point an object to object`?

Comment: window.window returns window object and window.window.window also returns an window. How did they implement that

Comment: okay, i'm answering to this now.

Answer (score 10):

window.window or window.window.window and so on, that's not an implementation, that's a side-effect

consider this

```
var win = {};
win.win = win;
```

now

```
win.win === win
```

and

```
win.win.win === win
```

so what they could have done is like

```
var window = this;
```

which is actually same as

```
this.window = this;
```

because all the variables declared in global scope are properties of **this**, so doing such thing resulted in `window.window.window.window....`

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the `Object.prototype` like this:

```
Object.prototype.mySuperReference = {a: 42};
```

Now any object you create will have a `mySuperReference` property. For example:

```
Object.prototype.mySuperReference = {a: 42};
var z = {};
z.mySuperReference
Object {a: 42}
```

I suspect `window` does this because it is special -- part of the API. I haven't had a need to do something like the above in anything I've written. It is called monkey patching and it is generally a bad idea. But this would let you make the reference work just like `window`.

To make it behave like `window`, simply add a reference to `window` too:

```
window = Object.prototype.mySuperReference = {a: 42};
```

And now:

```
mySuperReference.mySuperReference.mySuperReference
Object {a: 42}
```

Comment: @GMR you're welcome -- one of the reasons that this is a bad idea is it will cause issues with garbage collection (getting rid of unused variables). At least I think it will -- you'd have to test it to be sure but it is likely to confuse the GC algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

> so my question how to infinitely point an object to object and how
>   that helps to avoid doing var window = this;

[Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-global-object) says

> In addition to the properties defined in this specification the global
>   object may have additional host defined properties. This may include a
>   property whose value is the global object itself; for example, in the
>   HTML document object model the **window property of the global object is
>   the global object itself.**

So to answer your question - This `global` object has `window` as one of the property (which is again a global object). By assigning window to itself allows all `window` properties to have a global context available in all scopes without caching the global context  - `this`. In short, it allows window properties and methods to be invoked globally without doing `window.alert()` etc.

Otherwise how would you invoke `window.alert()` simply as `alert()` since alert is not defined in a global context.