# What is the use of cyclic reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, circular-reference

I was wondering despite of memory leak, what is the use of a circular reference in javascript? Even `window` object in the browser is circular referenced like `window.window.window .....`. Why we are using it and where we can use it. What are the good parts of it?

Comment: One use-case that comes to mind is for [polyfilling](https://github.com/polygonplanet/weakmap-polyfill/blob/master/weakmap-polyfill.js) the [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) class.

Comment: circular reference won't lead to memory leak in modern browsers

Comment: @obfish care to elaborate more? How do the garbage collection tell if the cyclic ref is still in use?

Comment: @SamuelToh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347203/circular-references-in-javascript-garbage-collector

Comment: @patrick well just `WeakMap = ...` would also work in non-strict mode.

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm referring to the implementation, not the actual act of polyfilling...

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering despite of memory leak,

There is no memory leak, two objects that reference each other but are not linked anywhere else get garbage collected. The `window` object will never be collected, so it doesn't matter here nevertheless.

> what is the use of a circular reference in javascript?

Like in any other language they can be used for various structures, such as trees (parent <-> child), linked lists (left <-> right) and many-to-many relationships (students <-> classes). Not having them would complicate some forms of traversal and would make programs significantly slower.

> Why is window.window a circular reference?

`window` is not only an object, but it is also the most global scope where all variables are finally looked up. When you use any global variable, such as `setTimeout`, it gets looked up in the global scope, and therefore the `window` object.

```
 window.setTimeout === /*window.*/setTimeout
```

Now if you want to refer to the global object, it has to be looked up in the global scope, which is itself the global object.

```
 window.window === /*window.*/window
```

Therefore just the `window` already accesses the circular reference, it is the reason why the global object can be found at all. Otherwise `window` would have to be a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

see this page, great reasons are there
[Why window.window property exists?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window)

> The point of having the window property refer to the object itself, was likely to make it easy to refer to the global object. Otherwise, you'd have to do a manual var window = this; assignment at the top of your script.
>
> Another reason, is that without this property you wouldn't be able to write, for example, "window.open('http://google.com/')". You'd have to use "open('http://google.com/')" instead.

.

and see this answer also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35788599/1475257