# Why does the "window" object have so many nested "window" objects?

Tags: javascript, object, nested, window

For example, you could use the `window` object to call the `alert` function:

```
window.alert("Hello World!");
```

You could also use the `window` object within the `window` object:

```
window.window.alert("Hello World!");
```

Heck, you could even do this:

```
window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.alert("Hello World!");
```

I know this is ridiculous and no sane developer would do this in real life but why is this possible?

Why are there so many nested `window` objects?

Comment: Uh, rather than "nested" it seems they are all links to the same object. Or rather a single link that you go over many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.window in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788475/window-window-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every global variable is a property of the global object. `window` is global, therefore `window.window` must exist and reference itself:

```js
console.log(window.window === window)
```

> but why is this possible?

It's just a cyclic reference. The value of the property is the object itself. Simple example:

```js
var foo = {
  bar: 42
};
foo.foo = foo;
console.log(foo.bar);
console.log(foo.foo.bar);
console.log(foo.foo.foo.bar);
```

You have cyclic references in the DOM as well:

```js
var body = document.body;
console.log(body.parentNode.children[1] === body);
```

Answer (score 2):

They're not nested objects - they're just all the exact same object. It is (kind of) a property of itself (because all global objects are properties of the `window` object, and `window` is global...):

```js
var myGlobal = "Hello!";
console.log(window.myGlobal == window.window.myGlobal);
console.log(window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window.myGlobal == myGlobal);
```

It's called *cyclic* because it's infinitely nested - here's essentially how it looks:

```
window = {
    //All the globals and other stuff
    window: {
        //All the globals and other stuff
        window: {
            //All the globals and other stuff
            //...
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> The point of having the window property refer to the object itself,
>   was likely to make it easy to refer to the global object. Otherwise,
>   you'd have to do a manual var window = this; assignment at the top of
>   your script.

as describe here: [window.window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window)

The window property of a Window object points to the window object itself. Thus, the following expressions all return the same window object:

```
window.window
window.window.window
window.window.window.window
// ...
```

To create your own nested object:

```
myObject = {}
myObject.myObject = myObject
```